# Buffer.from(<string>, 'hex') equivalent in Python

Tags: javascript, python, typescript, hex, base58

I have a typescript library that I need to translate into Python. I am using the library [bs58](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/bs58) in Typescript and its equivalent [base58](https://github.com/keis/base58) library in python.

My problem is coming when I try to replicate this:

```js
const decodedTxHash = Buffer.from('34cc2932f90774851410a536e3db2c2e61266a1587fbc15e7e9c79b41631ac74', 'hex')
        
const nearBurnTxHash = bs58.encode(decodedTxHash)
```

This results in: `4Z6m9qjt9BNxTF1SdDw3bzYGXYzMp2gTmwRy5AJxpNps`

What would be the way to get the same result in Python? I can tell you that I tried all I could think of about making it into a bytearray, feeding it as a string as bytes, nothing gave me the same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your title you're only asking on how to convert hex into bytes which can simply be archived by `bytes.fromhex("<some hex in here>")`.
A full working example for your code will be:

```py
import base58
raw_bytes = bytes.fromhex("34cc2932f90774851410a536e3db2c2e61266a1587fbc15e7e9c79b41631ac74")
b58_encoded = base58.b58encode(raw_bytes)

print(b58_encoded)
```

Comment: I swear I tho I tried that! Thank you very much @WolverinDEV!